# Extend a class or pass in vars?

Tags: php

I have a class full of methods, these methods rely on a number of vars which change, eg. I change the table name that the class is altering.

What is the best way to approach the situation?

1. Create a class that sets the vars and in this class extend the class that has all of the methods.
2. Create the class with the methods and pass in the vars in the constructor.
3. Another way?

What is the general rule of thumb for deciding which way to approach this situation?

This:

```
class Happy extends Emotions{

    protected $table = 'happy';

}

class Emotions {


     //lots of methods
}
```

Or:

```
class Emotions {

  private $table;

  public function __construct($table){

      $this->table = $table;
  }
   //lots of methods
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for without seeing code but it seems you are looking for Dependency Injection: http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

Both way has some pros and cons
If you go with the first way that means you create a new class and extends it to main Emotion class.
This approach will increase maintenance cost i.e. you have to manage multiple classes.

If you go with the second approach it will increase the complexity.

My suggestion is if you are a one man show you go with the second way, it will increase the complexity that you can handle as you codded it and it will decrease the maintenance cost as it is single class.

and if you are a team go with the first approach.